# spark-submit --files hdfs://file get cached in /tmp on driver

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm running a spark-submit like this:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client 
             --master yarn 
             --conf spark.files.overwrite=true 
             --conf spark.local.dir='/my/other/tmp/with/more/space' 
             --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Djava.io.tmpdir=/my/other/tmp/with/more/space' 
             --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Djava.io.tmpdir=/my/other/tmp/with/more/space'
             --files hdfs:///a_big_file.binary,hdfs:///another_big_file.binary 
              ... etc.
```

I need to add these two binary-files to the nodes in this way, since they are parsed by an external `*.dll`/`*.so` in the workers which can just process local files.

Now running in `yarn=master deploy-mode=client` my node gets driver and therefore pulls the files from hdfs to `/tmp` directory. Since these files are pretty big it fills up my limited `/tmp` directory pretty fast.

I wonder if anybody can point out the setting to change this path from `/tmp` to `/my/other/tmp/with/more/space` since I already set the arguments `spark.local.dir`, `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`.

Thank you,
Maffe

Answer (score 0):

If you already have those files on hdfs, you should not pass them as `--files` argument. `--files` should be used to create a local copy of some static data on each executor node. In your case you should pass file locations as spark job arguments to access later.

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what i pointed out. I need these files locally since the third-party tool can't load them from hdfs, but just from a local file.